# What is this actually asking for?

Tags: analysis

I have been asked the following question 'Critically evaluate different techniques used to solve problems on series and parallel RLC circuits using AC theory'. I am not sure what this question actually means. As far as I can see there is a standard mathematical way of looking at RLC circuits. I can't see any reference to different techniques. Or is this referring to evaluating the different steps of the standard solution. In which case again I am stuck, because these are well defined steps that are used in practice. My final thought is that some of these analyses involve differential equations. Does this refer to different ways of solving these equations? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This question may be better received at [electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).